# Aspect method of a parent class of a RestController does not trigger advice logic

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, spring-aop, spring-restcontroller

I have some construct I'd really love to use an aspect on. I want to let my RestController inherit from a class which yields special logging methods which

1. log to the standard logback output
2. fires a http request to a service which does stuff with the log
   message as well **(done by the aspect)**

I created an annotation with which I mark the method I want to aspect so the pointcut cant filter it. Special case is that this method is declared within the parent class of the RestController.

The aspect is not running even tho IntelliJ is marking the method as being used by the aspect, which tells me the pointcut has to be working?

[image]

Please see my code and check what I've might missed out to get it to work.

**ApplicationClass**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.xetra.experimental")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AopTryoutApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopTryoutApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**RestController**

```
@RestController
public class Endpoint extends SimpleLogger {
  @GetMapping("/endpoint")
  public void doStuff(){
    log("foo");
  }
}
```

**Parent class for RestController**

```
public class SimpleLogger implements EndpointLogger{
  @AspectAnnotation
  public void log(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
  }
}
```

**Interface for parent class (heard that aspected methods need interfaces)**

```
public interface EndpointLogger {
  void log(String msg);
}
```

**Annotation my aspect should pointcut to**

```
@Inherited
public @interface AspectAnnotation {
}
```

**Spring AOP aspect**

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.xetra.experimental.aoptryout.AspectAnnotation)")
  public void methods() {
  }

  @Before("methods()")
  public void beforeMethodExecution(JoinPoint jp) {
    System.out.println("Aspect ran!!!!");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, **calls within the target object are by definition not intercepted**.

You can find more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#Supported%20Pointcut%20Designators).

The call to `log` method is not intercepted since it's made from the `doStuff` method belonging to the same target object.

Now, any call to `log` method will be intercepted as long it's made externally from another object (not the same target object).

#### Questions

**So if I use SimpleLogger as a component and not a parent class within the Endpoint it will work aye?**

Yes, you are right!

**Is there any way to get this to work anyway? Like using AspectJ and not Spring AOP?**

You can use AspectJ's **source weaving** to make it work. [Here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-aspectj-example), is a working example.

Comment: So if I use `SimpleLogger` as a component and not a parent class within the Endpoint it will work aye?

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work anyway? Like using AspectJ and not Spring AOP?

Comment: Updated my posting with answers to your questions.